# why blas is slower than numpy

Tags: python, c++, numpy

Thanks for Mats Petersson's help. The running time of his C++ does look properly finally! But I have new two questions.

1. Why Mats Petersson's code is twice times faster than my code ?

Mats Petersson's C++ code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <openblas/cblas.h>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
const blasint m = 100, k = 100, n = 100;
// Mats Petersson's declaration
array<array<double, k>, m> AA[500]; 
array<array<double, n>, k> BB[500]; 
array<array<double, n>, m> CC[500]; 
// My declaration
array<array<double, k>, m> AA1; 
array<array<double, n>, k> BB1; 
array<array<double, n>, m> CC1; 

int main(void) {
    CBLAS_ORDER Order = CblasRowMajor;
    CBLAS_TRANSPOSE TransA = CblasNoTrans, TransB = CblasNoTrans;

    const float alpha = 1;
    const float beta = 0;
    const int lda = k;
    const int ldb = n;
    const int ldc = n;
    default_random_engine r_engine(time(0));
    uniform_real_distribution<double> uniform(0, 1);

    double dur = 0;
    clock_t start,end;
    double total = 0;
    // Mats Petersson's initialization and computation
    for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        for (array<array<double, k>, m>::iterator iter = AA[i].begin(); iter != AA[i].end(); ++iter) {
            for (double &number : (*iter))
                number = uniform(r_engine);
        }
        for (array<array<double, n>, k>::iterator iter = BB[i].begin(); iter != BB[i].end(); ++iter) {
            for (double &number : (*iter))
                number = uniform(r_engine);
        }
    }
    start = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < 500; ++i){
        cblas_dgemm(Order, TransA, TransB, m, n, k, alpha, &AA[i][0][0], lda, &BB[i][0][0], ldb, beta, &CC[i][0][0], ldc);
    }
    end = clock();
    dur += (double)(end - start);
    cout<<endl<<"Mats Petersson spends "<<(dur/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)<<" seconds to compute it"<<endl<<endl;

    // It turns me!  
    dur = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++){
        for(array<array<double, k>, m>::iterator iter = AA1.begin(); iter != AA1.end(); ++iter){
            for(double& number : (*iter))
                number = uniform(r_engine);
        }
        for(array<array<double, n>, k>::iterator iter = BB1.begin(); iter != BB1.end(); ++iter){
            for(double& number : (*iter))
                number = uniform(r_engine);
        }
        start = clock();
        cblas_dgemm(Order, TransA, TransB, m, n, k, alpha, &AA1[0][0], lda, &BB1[0][0], ldb, beta, &CC1[0][0], ldc);
        end = clock();
        dur += (double)(end - start);
    }

    cout<<endl<<"I spend "<<(dur/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)<<" seconds to compute it"<<endl<<endl;  
}
```

Here is the result:

```
Mats Petersson spends 0.215056 seconds to compute it

I spend 0.459066 seconds to compute it
```

So, why his code is twice times faster than my code ?

2. Python is still faster?

the numpy code is

```
import numpy as np
import time
a = {}
b = {}
c = {}
for i in range(500):
    a[i] = np.matrix(np.random.rand(100, 100))
    b[i] = np.matrix(np.random.rand(100, 100))
    c[i] = np.matrix(np.random.rand(100, 100))
start = time.time()
for i in range(500):
    c[i] = a[i]*b[i]
print(time.time() - start)
```

the result is:
[image]

Still can not understand it!

Comment: Maybe numpy generates random number faster? If you want to compare the speed of multiplication, maybe you should take out the random number generation part.

Comment: Try `g++ -O2 -march=native -std=c++11 main.cpp -lopenblas`?

Comment: It's a good point; you definitely need optimizations for a fair comparison with C++, but the tricky thing is not optimizating away the code you are trying to time

Comment: Try using `mt19937` instead of `default_random_engine`, if that helps. Also to avoid hardcoding you just need to input the seed.

Comment: Are you sure that `a*b` in the Python code actually computes it instead of being lazy? (lazy as in Python3 `range`) / There is a missing `}` at the end of the C++ code. / Your `fill` command in C++ is filling each row with one value, which is different from the Python behavior. Should not be a problem however.

Comment: @user202729 `numpy.ndarray` operations pretty much all eager.

Comment: Are `AA`, `BB` and `CC` contiguous? the `numpy.ndarray` objects are.

Comment: I suggest you to check [this](https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/) link where performance comparisons are made between many languages. You can also see the source code of C++ programs and see how they're optimized for performance. Maybe these `array` are performing bounds check and numpy isn't.

Comment: My guess would be that your matrix multiply in python is only done once, since it doesn't actually change the value after the first time. How to actually prove that is a different matter... Maybe you could create 500 different sets of values and store the results (and ideally USE those values).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga C++ `std::array` objects are guaranteed to be contiguous.

Comment: You do not reset `dur` before you time your code, so it adds up to the previous timing.

Comment: thanks for your tips, it's my typo, and I have revised it. the result remains unchanged

Comment: I'm still convinced that your version python is skipping over the majority of the loop. A 100 x 100 * 100 x 100 matrix multiply is something like O(n^2.3) to O(n^3), so for 10000 cells, 0.15 to 1G ops. Times 500. That should definitely take more than a 2 hundreds of a second. I tried adding something like the "total" calculation in the C++ code, but my knowledge of numpy and related subjects failed me. But you need to make sure the C output is actually used, to avoid it being thrown away.

Comment: Sorry, that should be 1.5G to 1T ops for 10000 elements. Got my decimal points wrong...

Comment: I wonder if it is not better option to ask a new question than editing a question whose answer has already been validated.

Comment: thanks you very much, mats peterrson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I can't reproduce the original results, however, with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <openblas/cblas.h>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

const blasint m = 100, k = 100, n = 100;
array<array<double, k>, m> AA[500];
array<array<double, n>, k> BB[500];
array<array<double, n>, m> CC[500];

int main(void) {
    CBLAS_ORDER Order = CblasRowMajor;
    CBLAS_TRANSPOSE TransA = CblasNoTrans, TransB = CblasNoTrans;


    const float alpha = 1;
    const float beta = 0;
    const int lda = k; 
    const int ldb = n; 
    const int ldc = n; 
    default_random_engine r_engine(time(0));
    uniform_real_distribution<double> uniform(0, 1);

    double dur = 0;
    clock_t start,end;
    double total = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++){
        for(array<array<double, k>, m>::iterator iter = AA[i].begin(); iter != AA[i].end(); ++iter){
            for(double& number : (*iter))
                number = uniform(r_engine);
        }
        for(array<array<double, n>, k>::iterator iter = BB[i].begin(); iter != BB[i].end(); ++iter){
            for(double& number : (*iter))
                number = uniform(r_engine);
        }
    }

    start = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        cblas_dgemm(Order, TransA, TransB, m, n, k, alpha, &AA[i][0][0], lda, &BB[i][0][0], ldb, beta, 
            &CC[i][0][0], ldc);
    total += CC[i][i/5][i/5];
    }
    end = clock();
    dur = (double)(end - start);

    cout<<endl<<"It spends "<<(dur/CLOCKS_PER_SEC)<<" seconds to compute it"<<endl<<endl;
    cout << "total =" << total << endl;
}
```

and this code:

```
import numpy as np
import time
a = {}
b = {}
c = {}
for i in range(500):
    a[i] = np.matrix(np.random.rand(100, 100))
    b[i] = np.matrix(np.random.rand(100, 100))
    c[i] = np.matrix(np.random.rand(100, 100))
start = time.time()
for i in range(500):
    c[i] = a[i]*b[i]
print(time.time() - start)
```

we know that the loops do (nearly) the same thing. My results are these:

- python 2.7: 0.676353931427
- python 3.4: 0.6782681941986084
- clang++ -O2: 0.117377
- g++ -O2: 0.117685

Making the arrays global ensures that we don#t blow up the stack. I also changed rengine1 to rengine, since it wouldn't compile as it was.

I then made sure both examples calculate 500 different array values.

Interestingly, the total time for g++ is much shorter than the total time for clang++ - but that's the loop outside the time measurement, the actual matrix multiplication is the same, give or take a thousandth of a second. Total execution time for python is somewhere between clang and g++.

Comment: I am currius to know why clang has a total execution time larger than GCC. Does clang++ used libc++ and g++ stdlibc++?

Comment: I think clang just didn't optimize the initialization code as good as gcc, but I didn't look into it. It's too easy to get dragged into those sort of things, and not get to work in time... :)